# How to iterate and display nested map (map<string,map<map<string,string>,string>>) in vf page?

Tags: visualforce, map

I am getting the value of `map<string,map<map<string,string>,string>>` for controller. I need to iterate and display the value in vf page, But I am not getting the output.

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" controller="DealerReport">
    <apex:form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <apex:repeat value="{!map}" var="fieldKey">
                    key: {!fieldKey }
                    value: {!map[fieldKey]}
                    <apex:variable var="c" value="{!map[fieldKey]}" />
                    {!map[fieldKey][c]}
                </apex:repeat>  
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

smaple map: `map<productType,map<map<name,size>,quantity>>`

{Flowers={{rose=20cm}=10pcs}}

Comment: Can you post sample value of your map `map<string,map<map<string,string>,string>>`

Comment: {Flowers={{rose=20cm}=10pcs}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to display that kind of a `Map` as in one of your inner `Map`  you are having a complex type i.e. `Map` **(i.e. in 2nd Map where you have Map of string,string)** as key which cannot be sorted and hence, you won't be able to display in visualforce page using a straight forward approach.

Looking at the example you have provided, you can use `Map<string,Map<string, Map<string,string>>>` instead of `Map<string,Map<Map<string,string>,string>>`. So as per your example, you can have your data like `{Flowers={rose= {20cm=10pcs}}}` instead of `{Flowers={{rose=20cm}=10pcs}}`.

Having the data in the above format will make your visualforce page much simpler and you can show the data using this below code

**Note :** You will have to change the datatype to `Map<string,Map<string, Map<string,string>>>` and have the data in this format `{Flowers={rose= {20cm=10pcs}}}`, only then you would be able to use this below visualforce code.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!map}" var="fieldKey1">
    key1: {!fieldKey1}
    value1: {!map[fieldKey1]}
    <br/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!map[fieldKey1]}" var="fieldKey2">
        key1: {!fieldKey2}
        value1: {!map[fieldKey1][fieldKey2]}
        <br/>
        <apex:repeat value="{!map[fieldKey1][fieldKey2]}" var="fieldKey3">
            key1: {!fieldKey3}
            value1: {!map[fieldKey1][fieldKey2][fieldKey3]}
            <br/>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration format you are using `map<string,map<map<string,string>,string>>` is not right. using map as a key in the map is not the right approach because keys can not be sorted.
you should use map in below format and arrange your data accordingly.

`Map<string,Map<string,Map<string,string>>>`

Please mark this answer selected if it helped.